# How to target a container in jQuery that isn't a child of container with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I had this html:

```
<div>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
```

I need to target the container with the class bar, that isn't the child of the container with the class foo, while leaving alone the one that is a child of foo. Because the instance I am targeting is created by a third party script, I can't just add a class to it's wrapper.

Is there anyway to do this with JavaScript/ jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$('.bar:not(.foo .bar)')
$('.bar').not('.foo .bar')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/duNL2/)